# concatenate variable in link php

Tags: php

I wants to concatenate **$today** variable in url and ***0530&(India Standard Time)*** string. The url should be like this `http://example.com/check?image=true&id=Thu Oct 20 2016 19:29:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` after concatenation. Tied my self but still facing the problem. Anyone can help? Thank you

```html
<? php

$today = date("D M j Y G:i:s T ");    
 
    echo < img src = '"http://example.com/check?image=true&id=" .$today. "0530&(India Standard Time)"' />
?>
```

Comment: What problem? That's also an invalid URL.

Comment: What result does this code currently produce?  In what way does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: Remove the single quotes.

Comment: see this , https://eval.in/663805 : echo this  echo "< img src = 'http://example.com/check?image=true&id=" .$today. "0530&(India Standard Time)'>";

Comment: actually i am trying to echo image captcha. which has link like this `http://example.com/check?image=true&id=Thu Oct 20 2016 19:29:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` so i want to make request to this example.com url from my php code.

Comment: @Mahesh : see this https://eval.in/663805

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo '<img src="http://example.com/check?image=true&id=' . $today . '0530&(India Standard Time)" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a & in a URL, it's a reserved char. You need to use the urlencode and urldecode function to do so.

```
<?php
$today = urlencode(date("D M j Y G:i:s T") . "0530&(India Standard Time)");

echo '<img src="http://example.com/check?image=true&id=' .$today .' />';

echo 'To Decode: ' . urldecode($today);
?>
```

This will output

> ```
> <img src="http://example.com/check?image=true&id=Thu+Oct+20+2016+16%3A15%3A02+CEST0530%26%28India+Standard+Time%29 />To Decode: Thu Oct 20 2016 16:15:02 CEST0530&(India Standard Time)
> ```